# Get process id of the command of the command just after execution

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, command

I need to execute a couple of commands in Linux via python and store the process of the commands in database so I can kill it when it is needed. For each command I should get the process id and put it in to database when it is needed.

I tried `command & echo$!` this will return process id in output. I have to parse the output and get the process id. I need to know is there any easy way to get the process id after running a command?.

Output of above command will

```
[1] 7543745

command output
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the above run program, to understand how it is to be parsed.

Comment: the output added in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the subprocess module from within python:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('grep')
print(p.pid)
```

Comment: Hi ,subprocess.Popen("n2disk -o .") is giving No such file or directory 'n2disk -o .' . What will "Popen' will accept"?

Comment: Popen expects a list containing the command and options,e.g. subprocess.Popen("ls -l".split())

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to find process ID by name:

```py
import os

process_name = 'Jupyter'
os.system('pgrep -fl {}'.format(process_name))
```